# UWP App: MessageDialog ShowAsync doesn't work in OnActivated by LaunchUriForResultsAsync

Tags: uwp, async-await, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

When a UWP app is launched by an another app, the method `OnActivated` in the `App` class (the class that inherits from the upper class `Application`) is called. So the method `OnActivated` is overridden to add instructions that we want to be executed when the application is called by an another one.

Surprisingly, if the instruction `MessageDialog("Hi").ShowAsync();` is written there and the app is called using `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`, it does not work! It works only if the app is called using `LaunchUriAsync`!

As a trick, it works if I make the app navigate to a page and then I call the `MessageDialog("Hi").ShowAsync();` from the `OnNavigatedTo` in that page.

Any explanation?

Comment: LaunchUriAsync() also can pass parameter to transfer data, why do you want to use LaunchUriForResultsAsync(). What's your expected behaviour?

Comment: Obviously, because I need to pass data back from the called app to the caller!